# How to give allowance to take data from rest API?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, deployment

I have problem on deployment. I created my webpage on Vercel and there is an error "[blocked] The page at https://new-blog-obbght56s-effectiveone.vercel.app/ was not allowed to display insecure content from http://XXXXl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts.
but on localhost it can.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const baseURL = "http://xxxx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
  const [postz, setPostz] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {

    axios.get(baseURL).then((response) => {
        setPostz(response.data);
    }).then( () => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!postz) return null;
```

```
    <div className={liStyle} >
      {
      isLoading ? (<p>ładuje się strona..</p>) :
      postz.map((postz) => 
      <div key={postz.id} className={liStyle}>
    <a href={postz.link}><p>{postz.title.rendered}</p></a>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is a "[Mixed Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)" error – your Vercel app is using HTTPS but your Wordpress site is using HTTP. The only way to solve this issue (that works across browsers and that will continue to work) is to start serving your Wordpress site over HTTPS.

One simple way to do so would be to set up [Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/edge-certificates/additional-options/always-use-https/) as the DNS for your Wordpress site, where you would turn on "Always use HTTPS". Another popular solution (that requires a bit more effort) is to set up Let's Encrypt.